# Calculate a moving sum/average depending on date

Tags: sas

My data has the following structure

```
data have;
    infile datalines delimiter='    ';
    input customerid : 8.
        date : date9.
        opens : 3.
    ;
    datalines;
2123780 11APR2017   0
2123780 13APR2017   0
2123780 16APR2017   1
2123780 18APR2017   0
2123780 19APR2017   2
2123780 20APR2017   0
2123780 21APR2017   0
2123780 23APR2017   0
2123780 25APR2017   0
2123780 26APR2017   0
2123780 28APR2017   0
2123780 29APR2017   3
2123780 01MAY2017   3
2123780 03MAY2017   2
2123780 04MAY2017   5
2123780 05MAY2017   1
2123780 07MAY2017   2
2123780 09MAY2017   2
2123780 11MAY2017   3
2123780 13MAY2017   3
2123780 14MAY2017   0
2123780 16MAY2017   2
2123780 17MAY2017   2
;
run;
```

What I like to achieve is a moving total, average, sd, etc. for the `opens` variable (and many more), which contain the values which fall within the last 7, 14, 30, etc. days PRIOR to the current observation, by `customerid`.
As you can see, the observations occur irregularly. Sometimes there are large gaps between, sometimes there are several on the same day. Therefore, I cannot use `PROC EXPAND` (correct me if I'm wrong). Furthermore, I do not want to compress my date into e.g. one observation per week but keep them as they are.

The solution I came up with is an ugly piece of `LAG()`-coding and if-clauses. An example for one variable and 7 days:

```
%macro loop;

    data want(drop= lag_kdnr_num -- lag_mahnung min7 -- min365 minimum);
        set have;
        week_opens=0;

        %do i=1 %to 500;
            lag_customerID=lag&i.(customerID);
            date_7=lag&i.(date)+7;
            lag_opens=lag&i(opens);

            if ((customerID=lag_customerID) and (dsate < date_7)) then
                do;
                    week_opens=sum(week_opens + lag_opens);
                end;
        %end;

        min7=minimum + 7;

        if date < min7 then
            do;
                week_opens=.;
            end;
    run;

%MEND;

%loop;
```

which is giving me this:

```
data want2;
    infile datalines delimiter='    ';
    input customerid : 8.
        date : date9.
        opens : 3.
        week_opens : 3.
    ;
    datalines;
2123780 11APR2017   0   .
2123780 13APR2017   0   .
2123780 16APR2017   1   .
2123780 18APR2017   0   1
2123780 19APR2017   2   1
2123780 20APR2017   0   3
2123780 21APR2017   0   3
2123780 23APR2017   0   2
2123780 25APR2017   0   2
2123780 26APR2017   0   0
2123780 28APR2017   0   0
2123780 29APR2017   3   0
2123780 01MAY2017   3   3
2123780 03MAY2017   2   6
2123780 04MAY2017   5   8
2123780 05MAY2017   1   13
2123780 07MAY2017   2   11
2123780 09MAY2017   2   10
2123780 11MAY2017   3   5
2123780 13MAY2017   3   7
2123780 14MAY2017   0   8
2123780 16MAY2017   2   6
2123780 17MAY2017   2   8
;
run;
```

Due to the huge amount of data, this is really slow and creates a lot of unused variables which I drop at the end.
Is there a faster, more elegant way to get this result e.g. via a temporary array or SAS/ETS?
Thank you in advance!

Final remark: I want to use this information as covariates in a survival analysis.

Comment: Since you have access to ETS, this sound a lot like **Proc expand** issue. MoveAVG: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63939/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_sect034.htm

Comment: True, and I was wondering if I missed something but I have only noticed options which use a specific number of observations but no time interval. Which WOULD BE the same if the observations occur regularly. I cannot even include empty days to get such a data structure since sometimes there are multiple observations on the same day and I would'nt like to combine them..

Comment: How do you want to account for multiple measurements on the same day? Either a SQL or Array solution is likely what you want. Here's a basic example of the array method, except you would need to verify the date interval before adding it to the array. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/27e23c015eae7953eff2

Comment: Additionally, I do have the time in seconds available, so I would just keep them in the chronogical order. In my example above, an observation which occured earlier on the day as the next observaiton would be included in the XX-day window for (total/average, etc) variable creation.
Thank you for the link. However, once again I am struggeling because I do not have a stable moving window regarding a specific number of observations but a time interval which can include varying numbers of observations. Unfortunately, I do not see an obvious adjustement to your code which would solve this issue :/

Comment: If this problem cannot be solved I was also thinking about to use `PROC TIMESERIES` and combine observations in days, weeks, or even months to be able to use `PROC EXPAND`. However, I think I would loose information about my data, yielding in worse estimates for my survival analysis. Any thoughts about how severe this loss might be?